# How to identify login form variables

Tags: python, html, forms

I'm trying to login into website with `requests` module. Login form is in javascript I think. I need to identify the form names that contain the username and the password. I tried to sort it our with Firebug, I hover over the `Username` field on the website and here is the code:

```
<div id="ctl00_main_login_dvUserTxt" class="dvUsr visible">
<input id="ctl00_main_login_UserNameText" class="f10 b txMain tx" type="text" 
ondrop="javascript: return false;" ondrag="javascript: return false;" oncut="javascript:  
return false;" oncontextmenu="javascript: return false;" onblur="javascript: return 
false;" onpaste="javascript: return false;" oncopy="javascript: return false;" 
autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" readonly="readonly" maxlength="20" value="Uzytkownik" 
name="ctl00$main$login$UserNameText">
```

I did the same for password and tried any combination of those and none was correct.

I also look up the page source and here is what I believe is the appropriate function:

```
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE"  
value="/wEPDwULLTE2NjY0NzYzMDhkZBd9ab2vcPcoEfqJ+ZqlPm7gs1iA" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
 }
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

I thought `eventTarget` may be the Username form, it is not though.

Am I on the right path of finding the form names or how can I actually identify these form names?

Comment: Are you trying to simulate a login request, without directly using the form ? If yes then you may struggle with conditions like "if Page.IsPostBack" in the underlying codebehind of that page...

Comment: I'm only trying to log in into the website to scrape it later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/ or something similar to analyze the data and finding the elements you need, it's way easier then trying to build a parser on your own even if that works too.

Or a little more light-weight library: http://scrapy.org/

And the form name is `aspnetForm` and the username and password field is not described in your post, it's probably earlier in the data. try searching for `<form` and locate every `<input` in between to `</form`

Basicly what you're looking for is everything in between:

```
<form ...>

*all <input> objects*

</form>
```

Also, what you're doing.. is way easier to check in say:
Firefox + https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/

That way you can see the actual POST data sent to the server and you can ignore almost every web-parsing and just go straight to the POST part of your process. (might get some ID's from the hidden input fields but meeh.. you figure it out)

Comment: I'm parsing the website with Bs4, sure but the website requires to be logged in to see the content I need so you know.

Comment: Not really? If you use any sort of POST data analyzing tool all you need to do is TRY to login, and you'll see what elements is being sent to the server from your browser, those elements are all you need to mimic (i've written X^Y of webbots for games and shady sites).
90% of the worlds websites you can do with just that, analyze the POST data, write a `urllib.urlopen` (oneliner) script in Python and do a successful login. in rare occasions you need to fetch some hidden .NET variables but they are plain text on almost all the sites which a scrape tool can do for you.

Comment: Would you be willing to take my email and see the actual page source and help me on this?

Comment: I usually tend to say sure on that, i love a challenge. But i work 12h a day and these small "help-snippets" is all i can provide in the next 6 months sorry to say, i only got 1h of free spare time each day, the rest is work work work and travel doing pentests and stuff all day long so, can't, sorry :/ would love to tho.

Comment: @Torxed "POST data analyzing tool", what is it more concrete ?

Comment: @antitrust https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/ for firefox (as mentioned in my post) and in Chrome you can use "Developer Tools" which under the "Network" tab shows the POST data.